# playing video from localhost

Tags: iphone, video

I have downloaded a video from server side on localhost at this path:

```
/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/60584763-39F6-4124-805D-BEFDE453206D/Documents/videos/bar.mpeg
```

And indeed the video exists at this path.

But when I try to play it the screen turns black and no video is played.

I did it like this:

```
 moviePlayer = [[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Users/adrian/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/60584763-39F6-4124-805D-BEFDE453206D/Documents/videos/bar.mpeg"]];
    [moviePlayer readyPlayer];
    [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];
```

And when I put the same video in resource folder everything works perfect.So I assume the issue is with the path.But what's the issue then?

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];
NSError *error;
NSURLResponse *response;

NSString *documentFolderPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];  
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString *videosFolderPath = [documentFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"videos"];

BOOL isDir;
if (([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:videosFolderPath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir) ==FALSE)
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:videosFolderPath attributes:nil];
}
NSData *urlData;

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:itemString]];
urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSString *filePath = [[videosFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"bar3.mp4"] retain];

BOOL written = [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:NO];

if(written)
{
    NSLog(@"Saved to file: %@", filePath);
    moviePlayer = [[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:filePath];
    [moviePlayer readyPlayer];
    [self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];
    [moviePlayer release];         
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add that video in your xcode project

and just use NSBundle to get the path of it and use the video.

ex:

```
NSString *path=[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourmoviename" ofType:@"mpeg"];

moviePlayer = [[CustomMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithPath:path];
[moviePlayer readyPlayer];
[self presentModalViewController:moviePlayer animated:YES];
```

hope it will work.

Comment: and how could I add it from an external folder into my project?

Comment: i dont think you can use the file in that way , you have to add it to your xcode project.

Comment: But i did the same thing with images, but it is not working with videos:)